# Plaint text sharing(app attachments) not working after Gmail Updated

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I am sharing plain text to Gmail for last 3 years. using the below code.

```
public static void openFeedBackMailer(Activity activity) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "abc@gmail.com", null));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "put your subject here");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "put your body here");

        //Check if Intent available
        List<ResolveInfo> list = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email"));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "No apps found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

but suddenly it stops. 
After debugging this issue & got this issue is **occurring due to the Gmail app update**.

Answer (score 0):

I am summarizing the solutions here. Each of these worked for at least one individual.

> **1.** Stop the Cloudflare DNS app `1.1.1.1` if you have. Possibly excluding Gmail from within the Cloudflare app.
>
> **2.** Giving full permission(storage, background data, etc) to system app Download Manager.
>
> **3.** Clearing cache of system app Download Manager, this will then prompt you to open the attachment using any app, make sure the app you
>   choose is updated and problem-free.
>
> **4.** Disable the Gmail app in Settings, restarting the phone and enabling it again.

**Number 4 worked for me.**